# What is the fate of the time-duplicate turtles from the 2012 Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles cartoon?

Tags: time-travel, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

In the *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles* 2012 cartoon, Season 3 ends with the Earth destroyed and Season 4 sees the Turtles and friends go 6 months back in time, adventure in space then return to Earth and avert its destruction. Their past selves then leave the Earth with the Fugitoid and the Future Turtles & co. (whom we follow) then stay on Earth, taking their place. What happened to those sets of teens who went to space?

Answer (score 2):

This was never explained in the series. One can only guess they had a space adventure and possibly settled down with the neutrinos. It's likely that writers didn't have a good explanation to close the loop.